# how to route laravel 4 requests to variable depth sub directories

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to migrate our custom built reporting environment to Laravel 4.
Currently we have over 200 report pages. For organizational reasons, we put them in an extensive directory structure. The reports directory looks like this:

```
reports
  - main1
      - sub1
         - deep1
         - deep2
      - sub2
         - deep3
            - deeper4
.. etc
```

On the deepest level there will be a controller with methods to call.
I would like to use urls like `/reports/main1/sub1/deep1/action`.

How can I set up a route that will send all report requests to the right controllers? The depth is unfortunately variable, to make it complicated.

**edit**

We don't simply have report queries that we could load via an id, but each destination is a php file that might do all kinds of things to render a number of reports, based on user input. That's why to keep it organized, we put everything in an extensive directory structure.
What I'm asking for is if there is a way to route to the right controller in the directory tree without having to specify 200 paths?

Comment: Is it not possible to delimit your `path/to/report` as `path-to-report` (hyphenated)? I think you can then reconstruct the path with slashes and handle it within the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more information in how the URL (directory path) functions in your app - it sounds like the URL will point to a specific report. Instead having one ID per report, the reports identifier is the URL path?

Here's a stab at an answer:

You can use regex to match a variable length route.

```
Route::get('reports/{path}', 'ReportsController@report')
    ->where('path', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\-\_]');
```

Where that regex matches URLs such as:

```
reports/some/much_deeper/path-7
```

Your controller method `report($path)` will have the `$path` variable available to it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we currently have 200 "main" php files that need to be turned to 200 controllers. Although you are making me consider how much standard report pages we have that could be loaded as properties of a big report controller. It is a good idea to use that regex instead of a * wildcard that doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work, because a path with multiple slashes is not being forwarded to ReportsController

Comment: Can you show me the path that does not work? I'll see if I can adjust the regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, doesnt work. I am trying to get the path after "usrimg/".

`Route::get('usrimg/{imgname}}', function($imgname){})->where('imgname', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\-\_]');`

doesnt match anything with a slash.